# using php SOAPclient and getting error: "this page must be viewed over secure channel"

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to call a method with php SOAPclient from a web service but get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Forbidden ( The page must be viewed over a secure channel (Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)). Contact the server administrator.  ) 
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://www.ebri...', 'eBridge.WebServ...', 1, 0)
#1 /var/application/test-control4-xml.php(284): SoapClient->__call('GetDocumentList', Array)
#2 /var/application/test-control4-xml.php(284): SoapClient->GetDocumentList(Array)
#3 {main}
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.ebridgeservices.com/ePortalService.asmx?WSDL");
$params=
array( 'login' => $user,
    'password' => $password,
    'status'=>'All',
    'docType'=>'850',
    'fromDate'=> $from_date,
    'toDate'=> $to_date,        
    'partner'=>'OurPartner') ;          
$results = $client->GetDocumentList($params);       
var_dump($results->GetDocumentListResponse);
```

As you can see I am using an https address, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need a certificate .... i guess

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of this error is when your version of php is compiled without the openssl library. Simply put your php is unable to make requests over https connection.

Check your phpinfo() output and see of you have openssl or any type of SSL support.

Comment: I do have openssl support enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Feeding that WSDL to http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html shows that the links in that WSDL file point to http:// URLs on their server, not https:// . Might want to ask their support about that.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I hadn't seen that before.  I'm pretty new to this soap stuff.  I see what you mean, and now that you mention it I can see the http address in my error message.  I've tried "support" and was told they do not answer development questions, so still stuck for now.